# Syntax highlighting is off in VS code when using NET6 file-scoped namespaces

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-6.0

NET6 introduces file-scoped namespaces. If used, VS code struggles to render the correct syntax highlighting. Do yo see the same and if so, is there a workaround? I'm using a default theme.

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [C# syntax highlighting broken by file-scoped namespace #136886](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136886) and https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4884.

Fortunately, it's a known issue that it is going to be corrected in a future release of VS Code. In fact, it is already corrected in the 'insider' (a.k.a.beta) version.

**Edit 2021-11-26:**
For completeness sake, solution is in this Github comment:

> chrmarti commented 15 days ago
>
> > This seems to be fixed in VS Code Insiders. Could you give that a try: https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/

That is confirmed by other users in next comments pointing at release 1.63.0-insider as stated here:

> deckerbd commented 15 days ago
>
> > I'm noticing highlighting differences as well when using file-scoped namespace and records.
> > VS Code (1.62.1):
> > [image: VS Code 1.62.1]
> > VS Code Insider (Version: 1.63.0-insider (Universal) commit: c109637):
> > [image: VS Code 1.63.0-insider]

On the other hand, as suggested in some of the GitHub responses, it looks like enabling semantic highlighting does not produce the expected results because this feature must be fully supported by color theme used.

It does not work for everyone. For example, it is not the case with the two themes I've been lately using, [Night Owl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sdras.night-owl) and [Noctis Minimus](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liviuschera.noctis).

These is how it looks in my case with 1.63.0-insider:
[image: VS Code 1.63.0-Insider]

And the same file with incorrect highlight in 1.62.1 release:
[image: VS Code 1.62.1]

My settings are:

```json
    "csharp.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": "configuredByTheme",
```

Comment: Would be nice to quote from the links.

Comment: @ouflak, you are correct. I should have pointed at the comment where it is stated that the issue is solved. This is the [actual link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136886).

Comment: I'd suggest to edit this answer with the solution to the problem from the linked github issue:  turn on semantic highlighting for csharp, and this problem goes away.

Comment: @tiennen07, I have updated the answer. I hope it is much clearer now. In my experience, semantic highlighting did not produce the expected results. If it is your case, please, share your configuration, theme and relevant section in settings.json.